# call function to all items of sequence

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I am trying to generate a nested map in Clojure.
The problem is that.

- Firstly I have a sequence ("first" "second" "third" ...).
- Secondly I have a function by calling which with each element with sequence I want to receive a map like this {: first (function
  first)}, {: second (function second)} and ..... .
- Finally i want to gether all result to a new map {:first {...} :second {...} :third {...}}.

Maybe somebody gives me some an instruction or approaches how to do it.

p.s

So i create a draft of my function (it does not work).

```
(defn finder [sequence function]
 (for [x [sequence]
      :let [ pair {:x (function x)}
             mappa {} (assoc-in mappa pair)]]
    mappa))
```

Comment: Do you want the map to be `{:first {:first (f "first")} :second {:second (f "second)} ... }` or just `{:first (f "first") :second (f "second") ... }`?

Comment: I want to get map like this {:first (f "first") :second (f "second") ... }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` to construct key-value pair and `into` to construct the resulting hashmap:

```
(defn finder [sequence function]
  (into {} (map (fn [k] [(keyword k) (function k)]) sequence)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for advise!

Answer (score 6):

This is a nice occasion to use `juxt`

```
(defn finder [sequence function]
  (into {} (map (juxt keyword function) sequence)))
```

Comment: Hehe, I like this one better than my solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could functions like `keyword` and `into`:

```
(defn finder [sequence function]
  (->> sequence
    (map #(vector (keyword %) (function %)))
    (into {})))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can zipmap over two sequences of function applications, since keyword is just a function too.

```
(defn finder [sequence function]
  (apply zipmap (map #(map % sequence) [keyword function])))
```